# Create CPU load in the background for FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

My current FreeBSD box suffers from the Ryzen 1st gen C-state bug, and I've tried everything to fix it to no avail. The only thing that prevents random hard locks is keeping at least 1 core loaded. Currently I just keep a shell open with

`cat /dev/zero > /dev/null`

running and experience no crashes. I'd like to make it so I can just start a task/service that does this. I tried creating an rc.d script that does it, but it never considers the task started, so that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/null &
```

creates an endless loop running in the background

```
killall cat
```

kills the loop